# Colorspace like RGB, HSB, LAB

Tags: color-scheme

is there any colorspace like RGB or HSV or LAB with just only one float ?
With i could calculate?

And methods to convert RGV to the float and back ?

Comment: In what language? You can convert all these values to integers (or float), see http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rgb+to+int

Comment: it must be converted back. so i could calculate

Comment: The inverse "int to rgb" is also answered on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

There are tons of colorspaces out there. You can find a good matrix of "convert this to that" at [Bruce Lindbloom's](http://brucelindbloom.com/index.html?Math.html) site.